# Connecting to Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have successfully added a Leaderboard to my game but I cannot open it (with `startActivityForResult()`) until I have called `mGamesClient.submitScore()`.  There are already scores on the leaderboard so it is not the fact that there aren't any scores.

I am having the same problem Achievements.  I am unable to unlock an achievement.  The IDs for the leaderboards and achievments are correct.  Using `mGamesClient.connect()` does not help. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved after the Google Play services update to 4.1